# Проблема с переполнением буфера

Tags: c++, linux, c, gcc

Я изучаю переполнение буфера. Написал по  примеру программу с такой проблемой:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int check_auth(char *password)
{
    int auth_flag = 0;
    char password_buffer[16];

    strcpy(password_buffer, password);

    if(strcmp(password_buffer, "enter") == 0)
        auth_flag = 1;
    return auth_flag;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc < 2){
        printf("Не введён пароль\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    if(check_auth(argv[1])){
        printf("-------------------------------Доступ предоставлен-------------------------------\n");
        printf("WELCOME ARTEM\n");
    }
    else
        printf("В доступе отказано\n");
}
```

Было сказано, что если поменять инициализацию переменных password_buffer и auth_flag, то проблема с уязвимостью переполнения буфера исчезнет. Но ничего не получается. Посмотрел в отладчике: переменная auth_flag находится после password_buffer. Как исправить?

Comment: Проблема не исчезнет хотя бы потому, что само переполнение все равно будет - а это уже UB. Что до вашего вопроса - компилятор может соптимизировать так, что, например, эта ваша `auth_flag` вообще не будет располагаться в памяти.

Comment: Т.е. компилятор самостоятельно инициальзирует в своём порядке переменные? Я правильно понял?

Comment: Что вы вообще понимаете под инициализацией? У меня ощущение, что что-то не то... У вас инициализирована только *одна* переменная - `auth_flag`. А компилятор вполне может ваш код превратить в копирование строки, сравнение, и возврат просто в регистре значения 0 или 1... Это будет вполне допустимая оптимизация.

Comment: Как в воду смотрел :) - VC++ все это встроил прямо в `main`, без всяких переменных `auth_flag`.

Comment: Под инициализацией я понимаю занесение в память значение переменной, а также выделение этой памяти. Насколько я вас понимаю, компилятор сам решает где записывать и выделять память. Так?

Comment: Да, он имеет право это все оптимизировать.

Comment: Всё. Спасибо большое, понял

Comment: Устранить проблему желательно сразу, используя другую функцию : `strncpy(password_buffer, password,sizeof(password_buffer));password_buffer[sizeof(password_buffer)-1]='\00';`

Comment: @AlexGlebe, а вот это правильный ответ (даже если ТС о таком не догадывлся) на задание ТС. Перенесите в ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `strcpy` очень опасна при использовании на неизвестных строках. Желательно копировать **до** исчерпания размера буфера с помощью `strncpy`.

```
 char password_buffer[16];
 // копируем максимум 16 байт
 strncpy(password_buffer, password,sizeof(password_buffer));
 // а если строка не вмещается фиксируем конец строки прямо.
 // без символа '\00' будут проблемы.
 password_buffer[sizeof(password_buffer)-1] = '\00';
```

Comment: А два ноля -- это для надёжности?